# no overload for method 'PutAsync' takes 1 argument

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, httpclient

I am relatively new to Web API. I have written my code on client side in winForm as follows:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    List<string> param = new List<string>();
    param.Add(LblUnitsConsumed.Text);
    param.Add(LblUnitsRemaining.Text);
    param.Add(deviceIDtxt.Text);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    HttpResponseMessage rsp = client.PutAsync(WebApiUrl + "/api/transaction/updateDevice/" + param).Result;
}
```

While running its showing the error as "no overload for method 'PutAsync' takes 1 argument". It worked perfectly fine for GetAsync, DeleteAsync. But for PutAsync its throwing an error. Can someone help me how to resolve this.

Comment: `PutAsync` and `PostAsync` are for sending data. If you don't pass any data, what would you send to the server?

Comment: What does a string plus a list equal? Probably not what you think.

Comment: Do not access `.Result` of an async method. You need to `await` the result, and mark your current method as `async Task` or `async Task<T>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PutAsync() method accepts Uri,HttpContent as parameters. You can't pass both URL, data as one parameter. So please edit your code to provide the correct type.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    List<string> param = new List<string>();
    param.Add(LblUnitsConsumed.Text);
    param.Add(LblUnitsRemaining.Text);
    param.Add(deviceIDtxt.Text);


    string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(param);
    var requestUrl = new Uri(WebApiUrl + "/api/transaction/updateDevice/");
    using (HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(jsonString))
    {
        httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.PutAsync(requestUrl, httpContent).Result;
    }   
}
```

Comment: What type is used to bind the parameters in Web Api controller action method ?

Answer (score 0):

To add to what has already been commented, PostAsync and PutAsync are expecting some HttpContent object to pass as the request body. If the API truly does not need/expect any request body, you will still have to create this object and pass it in.

You can read more about the requirements of this method call and what you can use as HttpContent [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Hello for all my call to REST API I use this lib :
https://github.com/jgiacomini/Tiny.RestClient

It's make easier to call API.

```
var client = new TinyRestClient(WebApiUrl);

var response = await client.
                Put("/api/transaction/updateDevice/").
                AddFileContent(fileInfo, "text/plain").
                ExecuteAsHttpResponseMessageAsync();
```